# VS2015 nuget package manager not finding packages

Tags: visual-studio-2015, nuget

I installed VS2015 Update 2 and now nuget package manager does not find any packages outside of the "Microsoft and .net" package source. It looks like the nuget package source was removed. When I add it back as "http://www.nuget.org" I get an error "Unable to retrieve results from one or more sources".

Anyone else having this problem?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The nuget.org package source is still there after the upgrade for me. But if it ever disappears you can add it back as:

> Name: nuget.org
>
> Source: https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json

Answer (score 61):

This is a [known issue](http://docs.nuget.org/release-notes/known-issues) with nuget version 3.4, which is included with Visual Studio 2015 Update 2:

> The NuGet.config file in your `%AppData%\NuGet\` folder has accidentally been emptied. To fix this: Close Visual Studio 2015, delete the `NuGet.config` file in the `%AppData%\NuGet\` folder and restart Visual Studio. A new `NuGet.Config` file will be generated and you will be able to proceed.

Comment: This solved my problem, thank you.  After installing nuget with VS2015 Update 2 I only had "Microsoft and .Net" as a package source.  But when I deleted the nuGet file you suggested and restarted visual studio, I had all three package sources back:  "All", "Microsoft and .Net" and "nuget.org".  Yea! For others having this issue, I found my nuGet.config file at  C:\Users\Ron.RONDEV\AppData\Roaming\NuGet.config

Comment: In my case (Windows 8.1) config file found at:  C:\Users\<your user name>\AppData\Roaming\NuGet

Comment: Solved in my case after removing the package source from the <disabledPackages> under %AppData%\NuGet and then restarting VS

Comment: This helped me to fix the issue. Thanks a ton.

Answer (score 3):

I am using Visual Studio 2015 Update 2 and had the Original Poster's issue. My package source config file was not deleted but the nuget source was set to `https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json`. I had to manually open the config file and change the URL to `http://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json` in order to get packages to appear. However, I got errors when attempting to download the package I needed. So finally I checked for updates, saw Visual Studio 2015 Update 3, installed it, and now I can finally see the packages, download and install them (using the http address - the https did not work)!

Answer (score 1):

After Upgrading Visual Studio 2015 in September 16, my NuGet.config had been renamed as NuGet_temp.config. I deleted the NuGet.config file and renamed the _temp version as NuGet.Config.

After that all of my packages are showing again.

Comment: It worked to me, for some reason the previous nuget.config was breaking the nuget restoration, after recreating the file witht he same content of the previous nuget.config, it started working perfectly... good hint!

Answer (score 1):

For me it was a genuine temporary network problem. IVe tried again a bit later, and the error  disappeared.

Answer (score 0):

I am on Visual Studio 2015 Community Update 3. I had this problem. What worked for me is: open the Nuget.config file, and change the https to http.

Answer (score 0):

Open Visual Studio as administrator.

Answer (score 0):

I tried both updating to vs2015 update 3 and changing from https:// to http:// but they did not fix the issue.

In my case it was a local folder permissions error but looked from the error message as a download error. 
When I looked deeper in the output window I could see it was a permission error.

In my setup vs2015 is running on windows 10 and it appears the cause was that some recent microsoft security update had changed security on my home folders so that visual studio could not create c:\users\myname.nuget\packages

Once I created c:\users\myname.nuget\packages and gave myself full control over that folder it worked.

Weirdly, although I changed the config to http, the download actually came via https. The download URL shows as http in tools\options\nuget package manager\package sources but the output window tells a different story.

Answer (score 0):

Opening the visual studio installer and updating visual studio worked for me (minor update). Perhaps the repair option there might help.