# Unable to connect to nuget package source

Tags: visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-2015, nuget

I have 2 version of Visual Studio (2013 and 2015) on my computer, and since I installed VS2013 it was not able to connect to any nuget.org package source.

1. I do not connect to internet through a proxy.
2. I tried to clean the nuget cache and reinstall the nuget package manager in both version of visual studio already.

*C:\Users{user}\AppData\Roaming\NuGet\nuget.Config*:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <activePackageSource>
       <add key="nuget.org" value="https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/" />
    </activePackageSource>
    <packageSources>
        <add key="nuget.org" value="https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json" protocolVersion="3" />
  </packageSources>
</configuration>
```

When I tried to restore or install any package, VS keeps loading and after some minutes the message is:

**With VS2015:**

> [nuget.org] Unable to load the service index for source https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json.
>   Error al enviar la solicitud.
>   No es posible conectar con el servidor remoto.
>
> Se produjo un error durante el intento de conexión ya que la parte conectada no respondió adecuadamente tras un periodo de tiempo, o bien se produjo un error en la conexión establecida ya que el host conectado no ha podido responder 10.115.8.100:8080

**With VS2013:**

> Unable to connect to the remote server

Answer (score 0):

Please check that whether it has the nuget.org package source in your VS IDE, you could add it back if it doesn't have.

Reference:

[VS2015 nuget package manager not finding packages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36386895/vs2015-nuget-package-manager-not-finding-packages)

[image]

Please also make sure that you use the latest update and NuGet version:

[image]