# VS2015 NuGet package manager not loading any online packages

Tags: .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, nuget, nuget-package

I have Visual Studio Enterprise 2015 with Update 3. Recently, NuGet package manager stopped finding any package except the set of offline packages: `Microsoft Visual Studio Offline Packages`.

I tried opening different projects, restarting visual studio and went to the extent of repairing/upgrading Visual Studio.

I also tried all the methods in this question: [VS2015 nuget package manager not finding packages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36386895/vs2015-nuget-package-manager-not-finding-packages).
Nothing worked.

When I try searching/upgrading packages from Visual Studio NuGet UI, the *Loading* or *Searching* progress ring appears, but nothing is loaded. Task Manager and Firewall suggests that no connection is made.

Finally, this appears:

> [nuget.org] Unable to load the service index for source
>   http://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json.
>
> An error occurred while sending the request.   Unable to connect to
>   the remote server   A connection attempt failed because the connected
>   party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established
>   connection failed because connected host has failed to respond

I might be missing something obvious. What am I doing wrong?
Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Finally, I solved the problem myself. Posting the answer here in case if anyone faces the same issue in the future.

As suggested by the error message, this was a connection issue. Apparently, NuGet uses the environment variable for proxy `http_proxy` even if the proxy settings are disabled in Windows settings. I removed the environment variable and it fixed the issue.

In fact, the error was documented here: https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/2880

> Finally I found the issue, at least in my case: if no Windows HTTP
>   proxy is specified, NuGet uses (if present) the HTTP Proxy specified
>   in the environment variable http_proxy.

Although, I had the `http_proxy` set even before, NuGet worked fine. So, an update should have triggered the issue.

Thanks anyone who viewed the question.

Comment: Glad you have resolved your issue and thanks for sharing your solution here. Please mark your answer which is benefit to other communities who has the same issue.

Comment: @Wendy-MSFT I can't mark it as answer yet. I'll have to wait for another 23 hours. :(

Comment: After removing the enviroment key, **reboot** is needed in my case.