# Unable to load the service index for source https://tc.xxx.yyy.intra/httpAuth/app/nuget/v1/FeedService.svc/

Tags: asp.net, nuget

While building a solution cloned from a working repository, I'm getting the below error. Infact the url https://tc.xxx.yyy.intra/httpAuth/app/nuget/v1/FeedService.svc/  is correctly added as a package source in NuGet(according to Visual Studio).

```
https://tc.xxx.yyy.intra/httpAuth/app/nuget/v1/FeedService.svc/: Unable to load the service index for source https://tc.xxx.yyy.intra/httpAuth/app/nuget/v1/FeedService.svc/.
  An error occurred while sending the request.
  The remote name could not be resolved: 'tc.xxx.yyy.intra'
  https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json: Package 'ServiceLocatorAnalyzer.1.0.6533.24990' is not found on source 'https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json'.
  https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/: Package 'ServiceLocatorAnalyzer.1.0.6533.24990' is not found on source 'https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/'.
. Please see Error List window for detailed warnings and errors.
```

But, upon checking the NuGet.config file(below) in my AppData folder, I can see only 1 NuGet package source is added in it whereas according to VS there are 5:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <packageSources>
    <add key="nuget.org" value="https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json" protocolVersion="3" />
  </packageSources>
</configuration>
```

Is this an expected behaviour?

I also deleted, the NuGet.config file;  restarted my VS as someone mentioned here [VS2015 nuget package manager not finding packages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36386895/vs2015-nuget-package-manager-not-finding-packages?noredirect=1&lq=1) but it didn't work.

Any idea where I'm going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

As specified in the [how settings are applied documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/configuring-nuget-behavior#how-settings-are-applied), many nuget.config files can be read. One of them is specifying the additional source.

If you download nuget.exe from nuget.org/downloads and use `nuget restore`, it should list all the nuget.config files that apply, although that might only happen if no fatal error occur (and I'm not sure if a source being unreachable is fatal). If so use `dotnet new nugetconfig` if you have the .NET Core SDK installed, as the `nugetconfig` template clears all other configs sources and adds only nuget.org. THen when you restore (use `dotnet restore -v n` if you have a .net core project because the default verbosity is minimal), all the nuget.config files will be listed, even if their sources are not.

Once you have the list of nuget.config files that were used in a restore, open them one by one until you find the one that defined the bad package source.